# Can I solve Y-Δ circuit by converting it to Y-Y? Or do I need to solve it using Y-Δ formula?

Tags: current-measurement, three-phase, y-to-delta

[image: My question is for the 3(ii)]

[image: I have solved for 3(ii) using both ways, but my question is , which one is the correct way of solving this question? Why is the line/phase currents different for each method?]

Above is the picture of how I approach the 3(ii) question. My question is,which way is the correct way of finding line/phase currents/voltages? Why is the line/phase current different for each method?

[Simulation of circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcAWaAmAzAgbBjB2BSfZBNBADhCOusmoFMBaMMAKADcQ1l7kM03XiDzYo4EMLAIE0HOPowEnIXwEi09BGEH0IUmXLH00sAJz8z2yJjMYwVjFDkqeawWHxiEyZOP16hvL0TKaQFhhWYDaR9o7OygBOkmBiotReIhjG3GzJyKnUOhnexSZ5Kd6ZCNWZ5cn4mlliFHDN4hhsAMYgrfTpFK3tirA2IKFgsGC+lNgUeGbY2Gb4znDsPYSC-IL4FH7aumtjTDXQyNh7cBi8+GZoPEgw6xWN-dkgW5Lq-d29QwNkFQCjlnidsucEHgQTUMBQzGYqGD2A19kVBPtgYVfgB3VTtEHDNh4mppD5vIl4gRaYqEw5QYngaq+JlVYyMzxsyolBkk6rFPYHMqM0k8iwHOqM8VilnpSBS2UfQbvdkAB256TpxQgijYAHsRCBsH4TJAgUhUnobOdxIInJ0DWJjbazRQLdgaegJII0vruBBnaagWkmjAIB42EA)

Comment: Hello incognitomodus,  Thank you for the clearly formatted question.  Both methods should work and give the same answer when done correctly.  I haven't worked though the problem however I put a simulation of the problem circuit in your question,  with it you can check your answers and see what might be going on with you calculations.

Comment: Hi , can I know how you simulate and run the circuit on falstad.com? Cause I always get no currents flowing in whenever I tried to simulate any circuit?

Comment: That's strange.  There is a Run/Stop button on the right of the screen otherwise the simulation should be running continuously without input from you.  Try another browser or computer.  Otherwise I can't say why it wouldn't work.